# Erro na passagem de parâmetro para um Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Estou criando um script para pegar umas imagens na pasta e com isso gerar uma outra imagem, estou usando o Imagemagick, mas o problema que estou tendo é na passagem de um dos parâmetros desse script que estou montando e me da esse erro:

```
montage: unrecognized color `$BACKGROUND' @ warning/color.c/GetColorCompliance/1046.
```

basicamente, eu chamo o script e passo o parametro de cor, assim: ./meuScript.sh -b 00FFFF

e o script é esse, deixei somente o necessário

```
#!/bin/bash

MSG_USO="
Uso: $(basename "$0") [-h | -d | -b ]
-b | --background  cor de fundo da imagem gerada
"

BACKGROUND="4E9A06"

while test -n "$1"
do
    case $1 in
        -b | --background)
            shift
            BACKGROUND="$1"
        ;;

    esac

    # opção $1 já processada, a fila deve andar
    shift
done

# remove montagem existente
rm Montagem.png
# cria nova montagem
montage -background '#"$BACKGROUND"' -geometry +4+4 *.jpg Montagem.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está na última linha do script:

```
$ montage -background '#"$BACKGROUND"' -geometry +4+4 *.jpg Montagem.png
```

Tudo dentro de aspas simples é preservado, sem exceção. Veja a diferença:

```
$ echo '#"$BACKGROUND"'
$ echo "#$BACKGROUND"
```

Output:

```
$ #"$BACKGROUND"
$ #00FFFF
```

Logo, basta alterar para:

```
$ montage -background "#$BACKGROUND" -geometry +4+4 *.jpg Montagem.png
```

Também sugiro algumas modificações:

```
#!/bin/bash

background="4E9A06"
output_name="Montagem.png"

function remove_old_file() {
    if [ -f "$output_name" ]; then
        rm $output_name
    fi
}

function generate_image() {
    montage -background "#$background" -geometry +4+4 *.jpg "$output_name"
}

function usage() {
    echo "Uso: $(basename $0) [-h | -d | -b ]"
    echo "-b | --background  cor de fundo da imagem gerada"
}

function run() {
    remove_old_file

    while test -n "$1"; do
        case $1 in
            -b | --background)
                shift
                background="$1"
            ;;
        esac

        shift # opção $1 já processada, a fila deve andar
    done

    generate_image
}

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    usage
else
    run $*
fi
```

Comment: Valew, funcionou, agora vou estudar essas alterações, mas ainda estou estudando Shell script